# Android Bytes to Bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap, arrays

I have this working just fine in our iPhone app, but am having problems in Android.  I'm using the same urls/data in both apps.  When I set my image in my ListView to the bitmap that came from the bytes, the image doesn't appear.  The data is there.  Here is the code where I assign the view:

```
if (camera.snapshot != null)
    {
        bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(camera.snapshot, 0, camera.snapshot.length);
        image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    }
```

This is where I convert the string data into bytes:

```
camera.snapshot = responseData.getBytes();
```

The images are PNG files. They come in about 4 times the size that I need them for the listview image but I would think they would size perfectly to the bounds I set the ImageView to be.

On iPhone I simply use NSData and then use a prebuilt method in ImageView to turn it into an image. It works perfectly! What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the 4-argument version of `decodeByteArray`: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29.

The options would depend on the type of PNG image, so that you might need to experiment with. For a generic PNG, maybe something like this?

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDither = true;
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
```

You can see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine here. So you need to debug to try and find where else is the issue. i.e. is Camera.snapshot = null ? i.e. you might not be getting the data properly. Or there could also be an issue in the layouts to show the imageview. Try setting a predefined image to imageview and see if it is shown. This way you would be able to track the problem.

Comment: Ive done these things.  I actually have a default image in place in the view.  And the snapshot is not null.  :(